# Auto Clicker Functionality in Flutter

Tags: flutter

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photoroom.app&hl=en

can we do this type auto clicker functionality in flutter

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photoroom.app&hl=en

i want this type auto clicker functionality in flutter

so it is possible to in flutter and if yes so how is implement in flutter  can you explain please how is implement in flutter app please explain

Comment: I don’t see any auto clicker functionality in the app you gave a link to. Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speed.gc.autoclicker.automatictap


Please check this auto clicker app link